# How to configure Steep to find RBS files for a gem outside the stdlib?

Tags: ruby, ruby-3, rbs, steep

```
Cannot find type `Sinatra::Base`
```

ruby file

```
class StaticApp < Sinatra::Base
end
```

rbs file

```
class StaticApp < Sinatra::Base
end
```

run

```
bundle exec steep check --log-level=fatal
```

result

```
[error] Cannot find type `Sinatra::Base`
Diagnostic ID: RBS::UnknownTypeName
```

I use `steep` gem. It seems it is needed to require some files. But

```
library 'sinatra'
```

doesn't work.

```
#<RBS::EnvironmentLoader::UnknownLibraryError: Cannot find type definitions for library: sinatra ([nil])>
```

What do I wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: When creating a new tag, would you mind also providing a [guidance and tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/152892) for it? Esp. since "steep" can have various meanings.

Comment: @GertArnold, done. https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/152892 But it seems cached

Answer (score 4):

> But `library 'sinatra'` doesn't work ..
> `RBS::EnvironmentLoader::UnknownLibraryError`

### Short answer

```ruby
# Steepfile
target :app do
  repo_path 'vendor/rbs'
```

Create a directory structure like `vendor/rbs/sinatra/0/sinatra.rbs`.

How you write or generate the contents of `sinatra.rbs` is out of the scope of this answer, but check out:

- [rbs collection](https://github.com/ruby/rbs/blob/master/docs/collection.md)
- [gem_rbs_collection](https://github.com/ruby/gem_rbs_collection#using-gem-rbs-from-steep)
- [rbs_rails](https://github.com/pocke/rbs_rails)

### Long answer

Steep is using an `RBS::EnvironmentLoader`.

```ruby
# steep-0.47.0/lib/steep/project/target.rb:54
loader = RBS::EnvironmentLoader.new(core_root: core_root_path, repository: repo)
options.libraries.each do |lib|
  name, version = lib.split(/:/, 2)
  loader.add(library: name, version: version)
end
```

The `EnvironmentLoader` can find a `library` in either `gem_sig_path` (I think this would be a `sig` folder distributed in the gem), or in a `repository`.

```ruby
# rbs-1.7.1/lib/rbs/environment_loader.rb:68
def has_library?(library:, version:)
  if self.class.gem_sig_path(library, version) || repository.lookup(library, version)
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

In a `Steepfile`, repositories are configured via `repo_path`.

```ruby
# Steepfile
repo_path 'vendor/rbs'
```

For the directory structure of a repository, I took https://github.com/ruby/rbs/tree/master/stdlib as an example.

```plain
ls -R vendor/rbs
activesupport

vendor/rbs/activesupport:
0

vendor/rbs/activesupport/0:
activesupport.rbs
```